# Sharkovskii's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

the Sharkovskii's theorem states that for any continuous function $f:I\rightarrow I$, where $I = [0,1]$, if $\exists x$ such that $f\circ f\circ f (x) = x$, then for all $n\in \mathbb{N},\; \exists x,\; \underbrace{f\circ f\circ \dots \circ f}_{n \;\text{times}}(x) = x$. We note it $f^n(x) = x$.

Let $f$ be such a function. Then let $P$ be :
$$P = \{ x\in I\,|\,\exists n \in\mathbb{N},\, f^n (x) = x\}$$

How to prove that $P$ is dense in $I$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Why you expect that $P$ should be dense in $I$? Let $f \colon I \rightarrow I$ be the constant function $f(x)=0$. Then $f(0)=0$ and $0$ is a periodic point of any period, i.e. $f^n(0)=0$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In this case, we see that $P = \{0\}$, i.e. $P$ is not dense in $I$.

Another example is $f(x) = \exp(1-x)$, satisfying $f(1) =1$. But we have $f(x) > 1 > x$ for any $x \neq 1$ and therefore $f^n(x) > x$ for any $x\neq 1$.